# Openstack-install juju bootstrap error

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I am attempting to setup an Openstack cloud via Ubuntu's instructions. My MAAS server is up and running with my equipment properly checked in. When I run `sudo openstack-install` with "Landscape OpenStack Autopilot" as my selection, after I enter the admin email, name, MAAS server IP and API, the script fails with "A fatal error has occured: Problem with juju bootstrap." Here is the content from my command.log:

```
[DEBUG â¢ 07-27 11:15:26] â¢ cloudinstall.multi_install â¢ (multi_install.py, do_install, 137)]
   Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/cgaeth/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap
[DEBUG â¢ 07-27 11:15:27] â¢ cloudinstall.multi_install â¢ (multi_install.py, do_install, 143)]
   Problem during bootstrap: '{'output': 'error: cannot parse "/home/cgaeth/.cloud-install/juju/environments.yaml": YAML error: line 7: found character that cannot start any token\n', 'status': 2}'
[DEBUG â¢ 07-27 11:15:27] â¢ cloudinstall.utils â¢ (utils.py, global_exchandler, 63)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 78, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 144, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
```

Now line 7 in the `environments.yaml` file is the MAAS API key. I have checked the file and the key is correct. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: I may have figure this out. It appears that you cannot have special characters in your admin secret password. Changed the password and moved passed this error.

Comment: Write an answer.

Comment: That was the answer.

Comment: @ChristopherGaeth: He means to write it as an answer and not just a comment, then accept your own answer.

Comment: I disagree with this being put on hold or not reproducible. Use special characters it the password, especially at the beginning, it fails every time. Further I can find no information as to what can and cannot be used for the OpenStack password.

Comment: @ChristopherGaeth can you head over to https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/672 and let us know what characters you were using that caused this to fail?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you cannot have special characters in your admin secret password.

Bug report: https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/672

Comment: Nice catch! I've reported it in our bug tracking system if you want to follow along, we can move the conversation there and just leave this closed. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherGaeth : if you could visit the issue that Jorge filed for you and let us know what character caused the problem so we can test a fix, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherGaeth or even just post the character here so we can fix it.